# Python3: convert list of array

Tags: type-conversion, numpy-ndarray

I have a list of elements as follow:

```
values = [array([-2.47-3j]), array([4.7+1.4j])]
```

I'd like to have instead:

```
value = [(-2.47-3j), (4.7+1.4j)]
```

I've investigated the type and since the first is a numpy array, I've tried:

```
value = list(value)
value = value.tolist()
```

The error displayed is:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'tolist'
```

I do not know how to proceed. Any suggestions?